# Python MultiProcessing.Pool: How to use with no iterable?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

## multi-threaded processes

```
    p = ThreadPool(processes=10)  # creates a pool of 10 workers
    p.map(function_to_call, iterable)  # calls FUNCTION_TO_CALL with the first item from iterable as parameter
    p.close()  # closes the multi-threaded processes one all threads done
```

I've been trying to use this model, but what if I want to thread a function which has no parameters. Like run() . What would I put for the 'iterable' space, I've been looking all around and can't find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

The [`Pool.apply`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply) function is what you are looking for. Use `Pool.apply_async` if you want a non blocking call.

```
p = ThreadPool(processes=10)
p.apply(function_to_call)
p.close()
```